# How to split a string argument in a bash over multiple lines without adding space

Tags: shell, arguments

I'm running the following command:

```
some_command --flag "foo\
    bar\
    quux" arg2
```

This causes the string to be passed as `foo\tbar\tquux`.

I'm looking for a way to have this argument passed without being tab characters (or other whitespace characters added) *while* keeping the indentation (to make my script readable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
some_command --flag "$(printf '%s' foo\
    bar\
    quux)" arg2
```

would do it, though it isn't the most readable. That passes "foo", "bar", and "quux" as arguments to the `printf` command with `%s` as the format string. When fewer format characters are given than arguments, the format string is repeated as necessary, making this equivalent to `%s%s%s`, or all three strings printed one after another with no spaces between them. Finally, the output of the `printf` command, "foobarquux", is substituted as an argument for `some_command`.

Comment: Thanks I think the key is to not to put "foo\ ..." into quotes, otherwise it preserves the leading whitespace on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Using a helper function:

```
concat () (
    IFS=
    printf '%s' "$*"
)

printf '"%s"\n' "$(concat "foo" \
    "bar" \
    "baz" )"
```

This would output

```
"foobarbaz"
```

Or, putting the string bits of the argument into an array first, then creating the actual argument separately (assumes the use of a shell that has arrays):

```
concat () (
    IFS=
    printf '%s' "$*"
)

args=(
    "foo"
    "bar"
    "baz"
)

concat_args=$( concat "${args[@]}" )

printf '"%s"\n' "$concat_args"
```

The same as the above with a POSIX shell:

```
concat () (
    IFS=
    printf '%s' "$*"
)

set -- \
   "foo" \
   "bar" \
   "baz"

concat_args=$( concat "$@" )

printf '"%s"\n' "$concat_args"
```

Note that the function body of `concat` exectues in its own subshell (that's what the `(...)` does), which means that the change in `IFS` is local to the function.

The rationale for using `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` in the function is purely for aesthetics.  The `"$*"` will expand to a *single* string which `printf` will print.  The actual concatenation in this case is performed by the shell expanding `$*` with no delimiter (empty `$IFS`). Using `"$@"` instead would expand to a number of individual strings that `printf` would repeatedly apply its format string to. The concatenation would in this case be a *side effect* of using the particular format string with `printf`.

Or, the same idea (creating the actual argument string separately) but without that helper function,

```
arg=\
"foo"\
"bar"\
"baz"

printf '"%s"\n' "$arg"
```

`printf '"%s"\n'` above would in all instances be replaced by your `some_command --flag`.

Comment: I'm afraid these are pretty ugly looking than I expected.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan The first two variations essentially uses the same idea as in godlygeek's answer, but abstracted into a separate function, while the last variation would be portable to all `sh`-like shells, and would be what I would use personally.

Comment: Yeah valid point, the last command comes down to that. Thanks.

Comment: Why do these all mess with `IFS`? And worse, not reset it afterwards, likely leasing to mysterious failures later in a script this gets pasted into! If you just replace `"$*"` with `"$@"` the `IFS` manipulation wouldn't be needed, and it would be much simpler and safer.

Comment: @godlygeek I need to "mess with" `IFS` because I want `"$*"` to expand to the positional parameters of the function without any delimiter.  Notice also that the function body is within its own sub-shell (inside `(...)`), meaning the change in `IFS` will not be carried over to the rest of the script when the function returns.  I could have used `local IFS=`, but that would have made it work in `bash` only. Using `printf '%s' "$@"` would have worked, but would, IMHO, have been a bit inelegant as it's reusing the format string for each element of `$@` (it's essentially a loop).

Comment: @godlygeek Thanks for asking about this. I've added some extra text about it in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I did miss that the function body is a subshell, sorry. Still, there's nothing inelegant about reusing the format string - there's a loop either way. Either `printf` loops over N args and applies the same format string to each, or the shell loops over N args and joins them together with nothing in between before passing them to `printf`.

Comment: @godlygeek Well, the mechanics of the actual concatenation of the arguments is totally different depending on which way you do it, but it may not matter too much if you're only interested in the result.